# Python - Function to check if user input matches a condition

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that is asking for user to input a number between 1-10, the script will then call the function `Size` and will return `true` if the number is greater or equal to `5` and `false` if not. However, I seem to have run into a bit of a wall, I get an error asking me to define x, this is my code currently.

```
def Size(x):
    if x >= 5:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
    x = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 5"))
Size(x)
```

Comment: check your indentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared user input x in the Size function. X should be an outside size function

```
def Size(x):
    if x >= 5:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")


x = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 5"))
Size(x)
```

Or if you want to take user input in Size function then initialize x in Size function and pass just Size function then follow the second [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65194045/5929910)

Comment: HI toRex, no offense here, would like to mention here, my answer was already posted before your edit on your 2nd approach, thought to make it clear here, cheers :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry, I was editing that time. after modifying my code I saw your answer. Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You were close, you need to correct 3 things in your code.

- Ask user for input before doing checks in your function.
- Remove variable passed in your user defined function.
- You need to change name of your function for safer side to make it more meaningful, so I changed it to `funcSize`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def funcSize():
    x = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 5: "))
    if x >= 5:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

funcSize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define x outside the function. Rest of the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Size(x):
    if x >= 5:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
    x = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 5"))
Size(x)
```

The error occured because I didn't fix my indentation after the false statement.